# Should we have specific tag names for the Swift provided classes that replaced NSClassName?

Tags: discussion, tags

The classes Apple provides in Swift are named as `Dictionary`, `String`, `Int`, etc. I have a question that I want to ask related to Swift's Dictionary class method `updateValue`. The appropriate tags that already exist are "Swift" and "Xcode6" (it's a relevant tag I promise, let's not argue that). If this was objective-c I would use the "NSDictionary" tag. There is a generic dictionary tag but this question is specific to the swift implementation of dictionary. Should I add a swift-dictionary tag to reference Swift's dictionary class?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326078/2415822.  Things get worse with Swift 3/Xcode 8.

Answer (score 7):

Eh, I never have been a fan of the class-specific tags that people have used for Objective-C classes elsewhere. They don't really add anything to the question, and no one is following just the [nsdictionary] tag. If you're interested in the language, you use [objective-c], and if it's specific to a particular framework (such as Core Animation), you tag with that framework.

I'm cool with these just being tagged with [swift], and possibly [objective-c] if they intersect with that language. I see no need to create a raft of class-specific tags that most people won't use.