# Swift 3/iOS 10 introduces class name changes, how to handle the flood of potential duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, language-versions

I have started creating some Q&A posts regarding the changes from Swift 2.x to 3.  With the release of Xcode 8 Beta 1 today, I would imagine that users will start asking more and more questions about Swift 3, Xcode 8, and iOS 10.

Most of the class name changes are trivial:  `NSUserDefaults` became `UserDefaults`, `NSTimeInterval` became `TimeInterval`, and `NSDate` now has a Swift struct equivalent `Date`.

How should we handle questions about the rename?  Should a canonical community wiki be created that addresses this issue?  Something titled "Use of undeclared identifier `NS[Class]`" or "`NS[Class]` is unavailable, use `[Class]`?"

Comment: Maybe change the question to ask about the general approach when you see possible dupes coming in from new technology.

Comment: They finally dropped the NS prefix in iOS 10? Or is this only when accessing the APIs from Swift?

Comment: @CodyGray nope, all of the NS prefixed classes are still there, but there are new Swift structs without the prefix that have the NS-class as a `ReferenceType`.  See the [Foundation API changes for iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/Swift/Foundation.html).

Comment: `UserDefaults | NSUserDefaults`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults

Comment: IMHO new tag and be done with it...

Comment: Swift and Objective-C questions get mixed together a lot. I'm personally in favor of anything that can be done to make a clean start, even if this means being a little lax on the duplicates at first.

Comment: Another point is the renaming of OS X to macOS. What about tags?

Comment: @Sulthan [tag:macOS] has been a synonym of [tag:OSX] for a while now. We should probably wait until Sierra is publicly available to consider changing it, since it would impact all questions about previous versions of the OS as well.

Comment: I'm not sure we want this... I mean, will we create several questions just because the [toaster stabs you in the face when you don't RTFM](https://xkcd.com/293/)?

Comment: Is this really a question about how a developer migrates to Swift 3? If so, a canonical question & answer that points users to the Xcode migration tool first and then Apple's documentation can be used to close these questions.

Comment: @RoboticCat partially, although I would imagine it would need to cover existing developers starting new projects and seeing that the classes they know are no longer available.

Comment: If those questions were already asked, then we can just (and I'm presuming the renaming is just that, a renaming) edit the existing answers to append the errata that iOS 10 and later uses the new naming. Considering that Apple closed garden will force you to do the upgrade anyways, you can basically demote to background the previous naming.

Comment: i think those tags are way too specific to exist for a single class. when the NS prefix is dropped, it sounds way too meta.

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled by the [Documentation](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/)? The beta is coming soon.

Comment: @Knu the Documentation beta has been coming soon for 6-8 months...

Comment: @JAL I am participating in the private beta: it is coming.

Comment: @Knu if things continue as they are, winter will arrive first.

Answer (score 8):

This question actually brings up a more general issue with SO. The best way of doing things can change over time. Often you will have an answer with hundreds of votes -- but the answer and the votes are both several years old. People don't realize that a lower-ranked answer, with fewer, but more recent, votes, is actually a better way of doing things.

For this kind of reason, I'd suggest letting new questions grow around the new names. In some cases, the old answers will still be good, and they can be suitably modified and referenced. In other cases, the change to a new question, with fresh votes, will give a newer answer, updated for new circumstances, a chance to take hold.

Comment: Earlier today I posted a question with the NSSortDescriptor tag. It's specifically about Swift3 and SortDescriptor, but I could not create that tag, and I felt it was better to use an outdated tag for the general principle than to use only 'Swift 3.0'. So this 'new names' thing might run aground on practicality.

Comment: @green_knight I think tags for individual classes are way too narrow and should probably not exist.