# What to do about tags for classes and methods?

Tags: discussion, tags

This has been bothering me for quite some time, and it seems like it only gets worse.

Some random (.NET related - but I've seen Java-specific ones too) examples:

- [console.readkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.readkey)
- [console.writeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.writeline)
- [console.readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.readline)
- [sendasync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sendasync) - there are plenty of APIs in the .NET Framework that have `SendAsync` methods
- [socketasynceventargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socketasynceventargs)
- [downloadfileasync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfileasync)

We could consider all of this tags as actually on-topic since they all belong to some API/Framework.

I found some questions where the community agreed that these kind of tags should go:

- [Should we have specific tag names for the Swift provided classes that replaced NSClassName?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262885/should-we-have-specific-tag-names-for-the-swift-provided-classes-that-replaced-n)
- [New tag being created for a single java class](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295567/new-tag-being-created-for-a-single-java-class)

I guess my question is:

Should we keep those tags, and, if not, can we agree on how to deal with them?

Comment: You would expect a tag for console.write as well but strangely enough that is missing. I guess getting your line endings right is a real struggle.

Comment: What is exactly troublesome with those tags? Their lack of a substantial number of questions? Their misuse? I agree the console.* tags are kind of useless but sendasync doesn't seem unreasonable as a catch all to prevent tags per method, no?

Comment: @rene I just find them kind of useless. Who would search for [tag:console.writeline], for example? As a comment states in one of the linked Meta questions, are we going to create millions of tags that represent methods/classes? If I use 10 different .NET Framework classes in a question, how would I tag?

Comment: [sendasync] [angular] can work unless you also hate [excel] [vba]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can keep those tags.

We trust users with 1,500 reputation to be sane enough to create tags. (and after that the tag needs to get passed users like [Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/what-to-do-about-tags-for-classes-and-methods/367765?noredirect=1#comment588396_367765))

A tag is just that, a tag. It is not a watertight, international standardized, well understood categorizing mechanism. You can't say that a tag needs to be removed just because it happens to be the name of method, or class, or both.

If you find a tag that is a mess (questions that are all over the place, crap magnet, off-topic cesspools) by all means write a [burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) to organize some support and hands to help you out cleaning up and or removing the tag.

You deal with those tags on a case by case basis. Before you head out to post a burninate request do know there is a bit of a [backlog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+closed%3Ano+-%5Bstatus-*%5D) because writing the burninate request is fun, doing the busy work needed to [execute it often not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334584/reviewing-the-godaddy-burnination-freeze-the-tag-rather-than-burn).

Comment: "We trust users with 1,500 reputation to be sane enough to create tags." say that to the group of users that keep watch of the /tags/new page to nip the problem in the bud.

Comment: I disagree, because it does not add any value to the question. Let's compare two tags: "file" and "c#". One tag tells me that a certain language is being used, in which I may be proficient and thus qualified to help. The other tells me that the question includes files...somehow. It doesn't give me any relevant information. It doesn't tell me if I am qualified to answer or moderate it, nor does it group related questions together. So to get back to the originak question: I think those tags are pointless.

Comment: @DavidStockinger sure, post a burninate request for each one of them. Or post a competing answer.

Comment: @DavidStockinger Care to comment why you deleted your answer?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Personal reasons

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: I was going to post a competing answer to rene, but I just ended up reinforcing their point.</sup>

These tags seem pretty useless to me. They don't really fail the burnination criteria though. These criteria exist so that we don't spend hours doing pointless busywork on tags that, while trivial, are not actively harmful to the site.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   These seem pretty unambiguous to me, aside from the possibility that other frameworks might have methods with the same names. And they do describe at least part of the question content.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   They're about programming, so yes.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   This one is debatable. I don't think these tags really add much.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Pretty much. They're method names.

Also, let's take a look at the number of questions we're dealing with.

- [console.readkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.readkey) - 37 questions
- [console.writeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.writeline) - 179 questions
- [console.readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.readline) - 79 questions
- [sendasync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sendasync) - 57 questions
- [socketasynceventargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socketasynceventargs) - 43 questions
- [downloadfileasync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfileasync) - 57 questions

These tags are *small*, with only a handful of questions each.

Burnination is a *process*, and removing these tags just doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Note that I picked some random examples, there are probably dozens of them. Question 3 is what made me post this meta. They don't add **anything** useful, at all. Any question can easily call 20 methods. Are we going to add a tag for each one? We wouldn't even be able to, since you can only add 5 tags, so how do you pick? If it doesn't add anything useful, why keep them?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sure, the tags aren't useful, but they aren't harmful either. Of course we're not going to add a tag for every method, but these tags existing isn't going to cause that to happen. Also, in order to burninate the tag, it needs to meet *all of the criteria*. So sure, there's no reason to keep them, but there's no reason to remove them either.